# Can't find Sony Viao VGN-C25G brightness after Win7 (32bit) upgrade

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, brightness

I have a Sony VAIO VGN-C25G which I upgraded to Windows 7. After a while, the OS crashed.

I reinstalled Windows 7 32bit again. Now the brightness setting does not appear in the power options setting. This kills my battery fast.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot yet comment, but here's some ideas to try:

- Do you have a brightness button on the top of your keyboard? Typically it is a picture of a star/sun which is operated when pressed with the Fn key or function key.
- If you go into Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display, on the left, do you have an option for Adjust Brightness?